# Perl wildcard match of filenames from "ls" output

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @allFiles=`ls *.gz`;

for my $file (@allFiles) {
    if ($file =~ '0000*.gz') {
         print $file;
    }
}
```

I am trying this above code to print all filenames that have a prefix of 0000. Like 00001.gz, 00002.gz etc

Comment: try this if($file =~ /^0000.*\.gz$/){...}.  Or you can just do ls 0000*.gz

Comment: why not use `File::Find` instead of `ls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A close equivalent to the shell's [wildcard `*`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) in regex is `.*`. The `*` *quantifier* means that the pattern before it matches "zero or more" times  and `.` means "any character," see [Regular Expressions in perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions). But as it seems that you want *something* after the zeros then use `.+` instead, to match any character one-or-more times. To match a literal period escape it, `\.`

Next, there is no reason to use an external command for what you do. In Perl

```
my @allFiles = glob "*.gz";
```

The documentation is linked at the end.

Finally, *please* always enable warnings and strict.

Altogether

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @allFiles = glob "*.gz";

foreach my $file (@allFiles) {
    if ($file =~ /^0000.+\.gz/) {
        print "$file\n";
    }
}
```

The regex pattern matches: `0000` at the beginning of the string (`^`), followed by any character (`.`) matched one-or-more times (`+`), then a literal period (`\.`) and literal `gz`. Note that `.+` means that the `.` *matches* one-or-more times, it need not be the same character.

Adjust to what best suits your actual need and the directory content.  For example, if you want files with only digits following zeros, you need `/^0000\d+\.gz/`. To catch a file `00001a.gz` as well you need to allow for non-digits after a string of digits, for instance by `/^0000\d+.*\.gz/`.

See [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for a regex tutorial and [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html), or better [File::Glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html) for things with spaces in names.

---

There are other ways to do this. For example, you need to *filter* a list of file names, so

```
my @files = grep { /^0000.+\.gz/ } glob "*.gz";
```

The `glob` is in the *list context* imposed by [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) so it returns the list of all files that it matches. (In the *scalar context* it iterates through them.) The code in `grep`'s block runs for each and if it evaluates to true that element passes. It is the same regex, applied by default to [$_ variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) that is the implicit iterator (and aliased to the currently processed element). So `grep`
returns the desired list.

---

For your specific example even just this will do

```
my @files = glob "0000[0-9].gz";

print "$_\n" for @files;
```

This fetches all files with a single digit following `0000`, then `.gz`.

See the list of accepted *meta characters* in the linked `File::Glob` docs.